# Reverse vowels in a string, using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on an algorithm that takes in a string for input, and reverses the vowels of the string.

- 'hello' should return as 'holle'
- 'wookiE' should return as 'wEikoo'

Could `str.replace` be used as a solution?

```
function reverseVowels(str) {
    return str.replace(/[aeiou]/-g, /[aeiou]+1/);
}
```

I am not sure what the second parameter for the `replace` function would be. I intended to find the first vowel and then move on to the next one to replace it with. Can this be done just with this method or is a `forEach`/`for` loop needed?

Comment: What if there are three sets of vowels? Would `foobairbeu` become `fuebiarboo`?

Comment: Check this python script, you may get some ideas: https://gist.github.com/igniteflow/5026195

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do this in two phases:

- extract the vowels into an array
- perform the replace on the original string, calling a function on each match and popping the last vowel from the stack to replace it.

Code:

```js
function reverseVowels(str){
   var vowels = str.match(/[aeiou]/g);
   return str.replace(/[aeiou]/g, () => vowels.pop());
}

// example
var original = 'James Bond';
var result = reverseVowels(original);

// output for snippet
console.log(original + ' => ' + result);
```

Comment: That's so much more concise than the version I was going with.